# Is there a way of showing information from a firebase array as string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Basically, I have a set of tags done as an array in firebase and want to show them as string in flutter. Is this possible? I'm completely lost here.

I've gotten this far: but I'm not sure I understand what I'm doing here and it doesn't seem to work

```
class Tags {
  List<dynamic>? selectedItems;

  Tags fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    selectedItems =
        (map[selectedItems] as List).map((item) => item as String).toList();
    return this;
  }
}

class TagsList extends StatelessWidget {
  const TagsList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            height: 50,
            child: Center(child: Text('${Tags}')),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood your question right , You want to render the items that you got from firebase in your screen? if yes then here is a code snippet .

```
 void getDataBaseCarouselData() async {
    final data = await _firestore.collection("Carousels").get();
    carouselItems = [];
    for (var item in data.docs) {
      carouselItems.add(CarouselItem(
          title: item.data()["title"],
          description: item.data()["description"],
          imageUrl: item.data()["imageUrl"],
          id: item.id));
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

.get() return a Map that you can use to get data from Objects using the tags name ["field name in firebase"] and then you can use the List of object to render them into your screen .

If I didn't answer it please provide more information so I can get it clear . Thank you

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer!
What I'm trying to do is to have text show up depending on what selectedItems array contains.
All the other info shows up, but I'm having an issue here
   Container(
                                        child: TextButton(
                                            onPressed: () {},
                                            child: widget.selectedItems == ("Wind")
                                                ? (Text("More in Wind"))
                                                : (Text("Error")))),
No matter what, it always shows Error

Comment: Okay but you are converting the item to a String which make it unaccusable  as an object , if you just want to display the items as they are then replace the '${Tags}' with '${Tags.selectedItems[index]}' but before that you will have to fill the List and set the item count to Tags.selectedItems.length . I hope that this will help .